# Html5 canvas graph fill on hover

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm drawing a graph on a html 5 canvas tag from a array with numbers like

```
arr = [6,3,16,6,53,1,3,54,67,6,3,21,6,49,7,8,31,66,51,32,56,49,4,78,9,65,43,1,3,54,67,6,3];
```

These numbers will be the height of the rectangle that is drawn on the canvas and it will be filled white with a transparent background;

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 1) {
ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
   // Fill rectangle with gradient
    ctx.fillRect(
        arr[i] * 10,
        c_height - arr[i],
        8,
        arr[i]
    );
}
```

Users can hover these rectangles and then see some more data.
I can make them change color but if there are to many rectangles the site laggs a little bit, so my question is if it is possible to make some kind of big horizontal rectangle that will mask(white rectangles) without filling the transparent background?

Comment: at first try to move fill style definition from a loop - this will give you a small improvement :) and for the mask try to read about [clip](https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/canvas-tutorial/6_2_canvas_clipping.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** You can define the array as a typed array instead:

```
var arr = new Uint8Array([6,3,16,6,53,1,3,...,3]);
```

Just make sure the type (here unsigned 8-bit) fits the values. If you have higher values than 255 then use a 16-bit, or 32-bit, if floating point use Float32Array and so on.

**2)** If the color is the same don't set the fill style inside the loop. `fillStyle` is rather expensive as it has to parse the string and convert it to the color it defines.

**3)** use path to add the rectangle to, defining and filling each time is slower than to define all rects, then fill all at the same time outside the loop.

**4)** use a smarter for-loop by using the array entry as a conditional statement as well. Not only is this faster in itself but by storing the array entry to a value will be faster too as JS does not have to look up an array entry every time you use arr[i]:

```
ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";                // set fill style outside loop
ctx.beginPath();                          // make sure we use a clean path

for (var i = 0, a; a = arr[i]; i++) {     // fetch item and use as cond. for loop
    ctx.rect(a * 10, c_height - a, 8, a); // add rect to path, but not fill yet
}

ctx.fill();                               // fill all rects with fillstyle
```

Hope this helps!